# Javascript array in string, how to get it in an array?

Tags: javascript

Today I have been trying to create a chart using canvasjs. It all worked out very well. Now the script needs to get the chart information from a different site. When you create a request to that page, it return something like:
`{x: 0.33, y: 2},{x: 0.33, y: 1}`. This is my script:

```js
        window.onload = function () {

        var previousprice = 0;

        var dps = []; // dataPoints
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("priceChart", {
            title :{
                text: "Coins"
            },
            axisY: [{
                includeZero: false,
                title: "dollar"
            }], 
            axisX: {
                title: "coins"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: dps
            }]
        });

        var xVal = 0;
        var yVal = 100; 
        var updateInterval = 1000;
        var dataLength = 300;

        var updateChart = function (count) {

            count = count || 1;

            if (dps.length < dataLength) {
            var hihi = httpGet(location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+"/inc/php/functions.php?method=get300");
            console.log(hihi);
                dps.push(hihi);
            }
            console.log(dps.length);

            if (dps.length > dataLength) {
                dps.shift();
            }

            chart.render();
        };

        updateChart(dataLength);
        setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);

        }
```

So, to add an item to the chart I need to use (example) `dps.push({x: 12, y: 65})` or `dps.push({x: 12, y: 65}, {x: 13, y: 50})`, but when I get that from the url, it doesn't work. Probably because it's a string.

How to convert the string into the array I need?

Comment: "it return something like" something like or exactly? Please add the exact response to question. That seems awfully close to JSON and, if it is, you could simply `JSON.parse(response)`. If not the answer will be more complicated.

Comment: @phuzi I could make the script return a JSON string.. Will it work then?

Comment: N.B. what you're looking at is an object (or rather a pair of objects), not an array. Arrays are surround with `[ ... ]`, objects are surrounded with `{ ... }`.

Comment: Do you have control of the PHP that generates the response? if so yes, that will make it easier. As it stands it's only missing the surrounding brackets `[]` to make it valid JSON. parsing that JSON would then get you an array.

Comment: P.S. This "httpGet" function...is it doing synchronous AJAX? Because that's the only way you'd get the response as a return value directly from the function. And synchronous AJAX is both deprecated and widely considered to be an anti-pattern. Don't do that, it causes poor user experience. Use Promises and callbacks instead.

Comment: @phuzi I added the brackets, now it returns `[{x: 0.33, y: 2},{x: 0.33, y: 1}]`. But this list can be upto 300 values long, and pushing every value one by one by hand will take a lot of time

Comment: 300 values isn't that much. What do you mean "pushing every value one by one by hand"

Comment: @AaronJonk "one by one by hand"...what do you mean exactly? Just use a loop, then you don't have to worry how many items there are. Or, if `dps` is empty (or can be reset) at the time you fetch the data, then just `dps = JSON.parse(hihi)` will reassign the whole lot in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parse string to JSON and push all response objects to your result array.

```
var dps = [];
var responseJson = JSON.parse(hihi);
responseJson.forEach(function(item) {
  dps.push(item);
});
```